# Trouble when writing to a file in a loop

Tags: c++

Here I have two pieces of C++ code that is supposed to write to a file some data. The first one is below and it works:

```
void ParameterManager::Save()
{
    std::ofstream saveFile;
    saveFile.open(path, std::ios::trunc | std::ios::out);
    if (saveFile.is_open())
    {
        saveFile << "File opened. Begin saving.\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        {
            saveFile << "Hoppa" << std::endl;
        }
     }
     saveFile.close();
}
```

The result in output file is:

```
File opened. Begin saving.
Hoppa
Hoppa
Hoppa
Hoppa
```

Like expected.
The second one is below and it don't work:

```
void ParameterManager::Save()
{
    std::ofstream saveFile;
    saveFile.open(path, std::ios::trunc | std::ios::out);
    if (saveFile.is_open())
    {
        saveFile << "File opened. Begin saving.\n";
        for (auto item : map)
        {
            std::cout << "Hoppa" << std::endl;
            saveFile << "Hoppa" << std::endl;
        }
     }
     saveFile.close();
}
```

Where the map is a hash map containing 4 entries and it is a member of the class where the function Save is implememnted. The result in output file is:

```
File opened. Begin saving.
```

The Hoppa lines are printed in terminal but never written to file. I verified in debug mode and the execution write 4 times but the content is not written to file.
 I test it on a Virtual machine  windows 7 pro. The host is MacBookPro. I use Visual Studio 2013 Pro.
Can you help me please to understand why the second version of code don't work like expected. 
A big thanks for all of you.

Comment: I bet map has no content. What does `map.size()` gives you?

Comment: "I verified in debug mode and the execution passes inside the loop but the content is not written to file" Could you clarify passes inside the loop? Did it execute the write 4 times?

Comment: Yes it execute the write 4 times. And the maps is well initialized.

Comment: @OlaruVictor You should give us more code. The iterator `for` loop is clearly the problem, so find out what's wrong with it.

Comment: When it's *seemingly* impossible, don't trust the interactive debugger.  Add `std::cout << "map.size() " << map.size() << '\n';` before the loop and check the value.  (More generally, you can simplify to `if (std::ofstream saveFile(path)) { saveFile << ...; for ...; }`; no point calling `close()` explicitly unless you're going to check for success (a la `saveFile.close(); if (!saveFile) std::cerr << ...;`).

Comment: If you still can't see what's wrong, add `std::cout << "iteration\n";` inside the `for` loop.  FWIW, `iter` will be a `std::pair<>` not an iterator, assuming `map` is a `std::map` (horrible name for a variable btw - try to avoid type names only distinguished by the namespace prefix).

Comment: Thank you a lot, your comments really helped me to find the problem. The problem is that I tried to implement the class ParamerManager as a Singleton but I did it incorrectly. So the state on internal member is incorrect and respectivelly the call of Save function is not correct. Thank you a lot again. Now I understant why we ask to provide more code in questions

Answer (score 2):

Welp, I dunno, but it works when I use `std::map<int, int>` and input 4 `std::pair<int, int>` and use the same `for` loop:

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e694252e96aebab5

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

void save()
{
    std::map<int, int> mappa;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        mappa.insert(mappa.begin(), std::pair<int, int>(i,i));   
    }

    std::ofstream saveFile;
    saveFile.open("test.txt", std::ios::trunc | std::ios::out);
    if (saveFile.is_open())
    {
        saveFile << "File opened. Begin saving.\n";
        for (auto it : mappa)
        {
            saveFile << "Hoppa" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "PRINTED LINE" << std::endl;
        }
     }
     saveFile.close();
}

int main() {
    save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
for (auto &item : map)
    {
        std::cout << item << std::endl;
        saveFile << "Hoppa" << std::endl;
    }
```